# PowerShell ISE - Wrapped Find/Replace

Tags: powershell, text-editors, powershell-ise

The find/replace of Powershell ISE doesn't wrap the search (go back to top of file after end of file) (like seen in Notepad++). Is there a setting to toggle this? Seems to be the first editor I've used that doesn't do this by default.

[image]

Comment: Quick shortcut key workaround: In the PowerShell ISE, press `Ctrl`+`F` and type in the value for the `Find what` field, click on the script logic area to search at the top and press `F3` to search down to highlight each match per press. Once you get the [**"Cannot Find "Value".**](https://i.imgur.com/uLv9pr0.png) you can press `Shift`+`F3` repeatedly to mpve the search for that value back up in the same manner until you see the [**"Cannot Find "Value".**](https://i.imgur.com/uLv9pr0.png) window again.

Comment: just to mention, recently, Visual Studio Code has become a viable solution for powershell script development and it's find behavior is the one you want. Check the following blog post [link](http://mikefrobbins.com/2017/08/24/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-and-configure-it-as-a-replacement-for-the-powershell-ise/) to see how you can set it up.